# Django template control flow?

Tags: django

How can I achieve something like this in django template ?
django template pseudo code:

```
{% for key, value in dictionary %}
    {% if key == 'some text' %}
        <a href ='url/value'></a>
```

in python i would do the .format() thing and update string like this

```
for key, val in dict:
    if key == 'some_key':
        'this is the {}'.format(val)
```

but how can I achieve this in template ?
Thank you

Comment: Instead of pseudocode, can you please share the actual code you attempted, what errors you came across, rendering issues in your browser, etc? Also, have you looked at the very thorough and extensive Django docs on Templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you pass a dictionary to the context, just:

```
{% for key, value in dictionary %}
    {% if key == 'some text' %}
        <a href ='url/{{ value }}'></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```